# Creating a log file from command line

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm using the csc command to build a dll

```
csc /out:Test.dll /target:library file1.cs file2.cs
```

I tried adding the /fl and /flp parameters to the command to make it 
the following :

```
csc /out:Test.dll /target:library file1.cs file2.cs /fl 
/flp:logfile=MyProjectOutput.log;verbosity=normal
```

. But it doesn't work as the /fl command is not recognized.
 Links-https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171470.aspx

Answer (score 1):

The link you provided is for MSBuild which will call the C# compiler. You are directly calling the C# compiler which has different flags. You need to use the `/out:<file>` flag to specify an our log file. You can see all of the flags by executing `csc /?` at the command prompt.

Answer (score 1):

As @virusstorm pointed out, you are using the `csc` and not `msbuild`, which means you need the `/errorlog` flag:

```
csc /out:Test.dll /target:library file1.cs file2.cs /errorlog:MyProjectOutput.log
```

Comment: I don't think the /errorlog flag exists for csc. I t throws me an error. I couldn't see it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/listed-alphabetically) too

Comment: I see. You must be using a version higher than mine. I am using 2.4.0.62216 and it is definitely still a flag there.